# NavigationView gives some errors

Tags: android, androiddesignsupport

I tried to create a `NavigationView` for my application like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
```

```
<!-- Toolbar instead of ActionBar so the drawer can slide on top -->
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
  android:id="@+id/toolbar"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
  android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
  android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar"/>

<!-- Real content goes here -->
<FrameLayout
  android:id="@+id/content"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="0dp"
  android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

```
<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
android:id="@+id/navigation"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="start"
android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
app:itemIconTint="@android:color/background_light"
app:itemTextColor="@android:color/background_dark"
app:menu="@menu/drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

But then it launches me several errors when looking for `headerLayout` (the `drawer_header` layout exists, also the `drawer` xml).

It says:

> No resource identifier found for attribute 'headerLayout' in package 'xxx.xxx'

Both XML exist, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong...

I'm compiling using API 21 on Eclpse.

Why is this error happening??

**EDIT:** PLEASE, I need help... I still can't compile this... I uploaded my code to Dropbox to anybody who may want to help me... Still finding problems!

I've tried to add **appcompatv7** libraries, but they give me errors... And now my project doesn't work... Please help!

[Link to Dropbox here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/777xsfxopb8wwdr/AACAwHHzD7qYtTqBbCCa9xcSa?dl=0)

Comment: can you also add the error log?

Comment: May be a dumb question, but did you add the Support Libraries to your project? Specifically the v7 may be added incorrectly because it is a tough job. :)

Comment: I think they are added, but I think my problem comes from there, because it seems like my android.support.v4.widget.Toolbar (as an example) is not there! The toolbar doesn't appear there!

Comment: btw have you considered switching to Android Studio
because most of the android community work with Android Studio now a days

Comment: yes...also your MainActivity should look like this : http://hastebin.com/ijihorisev.avrasm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything was solved when I upgraded to Android Studio...

Thanks all guys!

Answer (score 0):

You should checkout this tutorial for the design support navigation drawer:
http://antonioleiva.com/navigation-view/
this tutorial also have a link to the github project at the end.

After looking at your code I can tell that you have done this:

```
<DrawerLayout>
   <Toolbar/>
   <FrameLayout>your content here</FrameLayout>
   <NavigationView/>
</DrawerLayout>
```

but this is how the drawer layout work:

```
<DrawerLayout>
    <LinearLayout>
        <Toolbar/>
        <FrameLayout>your content here</FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <NavigationView/>
</DrawerLayout>
```

in short --> the DrawerLayout should have only two children ([here's the official doc](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#DrawerLayout) which says so)

Comment: can you update the question with the layout you are using now (drawer layout with 2 children)
and also please add your gradle file

Comment: I made an update... I still find problems while compiling this project. This is being a really big nightmare!

Answer (score 0):

This is my example. I put the drawerlayout inside CoordinatorLayout because i dont want the drawer to block my toolbar. So you can see the nice hamburger icon animation.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="<your package name.your activity name>">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />


        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
            app:itemBackground="@drawable/drawer_item_bg"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/drawer_item_text"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/drawer_item_text"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Then you need another layout with the name of drawer_header.xml in the layout folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:customAttrs="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="156dp"
    android:background="@color/primary_color"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_white"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

The a drawable in your drawable folder with the name drawer_item_bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <color android:color="@color/primary_color_light"/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <color android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
    </item>
</selector>
```

And not to mention your theme in style.xml

```
<style name="AppBase" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_color</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_color_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/primary_yellow_bright</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/primary_yellow</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/primary_color_light_100</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/primary_yellow_bright</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/primary_yellow_bright</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/primary_white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/primary_color</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/primary_color_light</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/primary_white</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonAppTheme</item>
</style>
```

Finally do add this two dependencies in your build.gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
```